# Error change favicon magento 1.9.3.7

Tags: magento-1.9, favicons

I want change favicon in multistore configuration:
System > Config > General > Design > HTML Head > Favicon Icon
but when i try to use filetype .ico i receive: Invalid image.
and in tips: Allowed file types: ICO, PNG, GIF, JPG, JPEG, APNG.
And I think it's work in early version because i have custom favicon.ico in other store in this site.

Comment: And when you use a png ?

Comment: it's work. but yandex does not like png.

Comment: I find this solution:
in file: /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
line (100)
if ($image !== false) {
change to:
if ($image !== false or $fileType === IMAGETYPE_ICO) {

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if your `favicon.ico` image is well saved as `.ico` otherwise there are several online tools to convert the image to ico format, try this first.
2. Check the `_getAllowedExtensions()` function content bellow if it is present with the right content in : `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Image/Favicon.php`

   ```
   /**
    * Getter for allowed extensions of uploaded files.
    *
    * @return array
    */
   protected function _getAllowedExtensions()
   {
       return array('ico', 'png', 'gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'apng');
   }
   ```

Comment: 1. file is correct format ico. 
2. yes it's function like you write.